# Web based database interface for multiple (same structure) elements

Tags: database, grid, dataset, project-management

I wonder if there are ready database/dataset interface software (better open-source) to implement within company to follow multiple elements.

e.g. i have 1000 construction sites (elements) which all have same lifecycle.

- initiation (dates, types etc)
- projecting (dates, status, files etc)
- construction (dates, types etc)
- acceptance (dates, status, files, comments etc)

That is like project management for 1000 standard sub-projects (elements)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You surely need a CMS for this.
From what I understand you need to manage 1000 of websites.

Try this link, and choose one of the CMS which suits best to your requirement.

http://www.webdistortion.com/2008/05/17/13-free-cms-options-for-web-design-professionals/